# How to specify SQL column type for a specific database in hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, mapping

Is it possible to set multiple **SQL column types** for an hibernate property **depending on the dialect used** ? If yes how ?

For example, if i have a column of type `char[]`, I would like to create a `CLOB` type for Oracle and a `Text` type in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no, it's not possible".

The long answer is "kind of, but you probably don't want to do that":

Hibernate would do that automatically **to a certain extent** - that is, when you define (implicitly or explicitly) a property of certain **Hibernate** type, it will translate that type to appropriate RDBMS-specific **SQL** type. [Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) and its descendants are responsible for that translation.

You could influence how that translation occurs - again, to a certain extent - by extending the dialect(s) you're working with (like [Oracle](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle10gDialect.html) or [SQL Server](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2008Dialect.html)) and registering your own column types. You're likely better off relying on default Hibernate type mappings, though.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I am trying to modify code that I have not written and the types in hbm.xml files are specified as java type instead of hibernate types and I did not know the difference.